# Test Apache config file from Python

Tags: python, apache, testing, config

How would I go about testing the apache config file from python?  I've trying using the "os.popen" with "text = stdout_handle.read() to get the result, but nothing happens.

Any help would be great :)

Comment: Can you please give little more details what you are doing, why you are doing it and what did you not manage to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to automate `apachectl configtest`?  Have you tried subprocess.Popen?  Something like the following should get you in started:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

args = ['/usr/bin/apachectl','configtest']

result = Popen(args,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE).communicate()
# result[0] will be the standard output, result[1] will be the stderr output
```

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects